# How can I use xdebug to debug a page with a link?

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

I am using xdebug to debug a page when a the link has been clicked. Meaning I want xdebug to jump to the page specified in the link and proceed with the debugging in that page.. Is there anyway I can do that? I am using PHP storm as my IDE..

```
  $menu_item_link = "<a id='menu_item_name' href='item-detail.php{$item_id_link}' {$tooltip_javascript}>
        {$menu_item_name} </a>";
```

Trying to have xedbug go to the item-details.php page ..

Answer (score 2):

on any page on your site start the debug session, xdebug then sets a cookie which auto starts the debug session.

Then just listen for the connection when you click the link

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm a little bit confused on what do you mean by starting a debug session. I am using PHPstorm...How can I listen for the connection?

Comment: These browser extensions help to make debugging with PhpStorm IDE easier.

Chrome --Xdebug Helper 

Firefox ---The easiest Xdebug or Xdebug Helper

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Browser+Debugging+Extensions

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/